# R optimization function

Tags: r, function, statistics

I wanted to use the optim function to get the optimal value for my variable "result"

The variable "`returns`" has proper values (503). I printed the values and its working fine.
However, I get an error where I call "`optim`":

> Error in optim(): L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn

Actual Code:

```
library(VGAM)
ini_val <- c(mean(returns), 1)
la_ret = optim(init_val, fn = function(theta){
-sum(log(dlaplace(returns, theta[1], theta[2])))},
method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(-Inf, 0))
la_ret
```

I don't understand why I'm getting *infinite* values of '`fn`'

Comment: It would help if you include the actual data you're using, or a subset of it which produces the same result. You can do this by copying and pasting the output of dput(returns).

Comment: Since you have a `log`, it could be that you end up passing it a zero value resulting in an error (essentially infinite value).

Comment: Get out of this body, Josh. Creating multiple accounts is frowned upon.